# JavaScript of a page not working while loading that page into modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, modal-dialog

I am loading a page into a modal in some other page.

The problem I am facing is that on change and on click function on drop-down list of the page which I am trying to load in modal is not working.

This is the function I am calling in main page.

```
  $('.MyModal').click(function () {
     // $('#formContainer').hide();
      var contentId = $(this).attr('val_id');
      var submit_type = 'edit_custom_content';
      $('.modal-body').load('/abc/xyz/create_page?contentId=' + contentId+'&submit_type=edit_content', function (result) {
        $('#MyModal').modal({show: true});
      });
    });
```

Modal structure is:

```
<td><a href="#MyModal" data-toggle="modal"
                 class="MyModal" val_id='<%=contents.id%>'>Edit</a></td>
```

I am loading `create_page` on this Modal.

The problem is that Modal is able to load that page succesfully, but drop-down changes are not being reflected.

Code is:

```
$('#select_contenttype').on('change', function () {
      document.getElementById("select_actiontype").required = false;
      document.getElementById("select_actiontyp").required = false;
      var _val = $(this).val();
      if (_val == "custom_feed") {
        $('#actiontype_event').hide();
        $('#actiontype_custom').show();
        $('#div_imageurl').show();
        $('#div_buttonurl').show();
        $('#div_buttontext').show();
        $('#div_contenttext').show();
        $('#div_backgroundspread').show();
        $('#div_buttonpicker').show();
        $('#div_uploadimage').show();
        $('#div_sidetable').show();
        $("#content_form_submit").css({ 'margin-top': '' });
        $('[name=actiontype]').val("");
        document.getElementById("select_actiontype").required = true;
        document.getElementById("select_imageurl").required = true;
        document.getElementById("select_buttonurl").required = true;
        document.getElementById("select_buttontext").required = true;
        document.getElementById("select_contenttext").required = true;
        document.getElementById("select_backgroundspread").required = true;
        document.getElementById("select_buttonpicker").required = true;
        document.getElementById("upload_image").required = true;
      }
      else {
        $('#actiontype_custom').hide();
        $('#div_imageurl').hide();
        $('#div_buttonurl').hide();
        $('#div_buttontext').hide();
        $('#div_contenttext').hide();
        $('#div_backgroundspread').hide();
        $('#div_buttonpicker').hide();
        $('#div_sidetable').hide();
        $('#div_uploadimage').hide();
        $('#actiontype_event').show();
        $("#content_form_submit").css({ 'margin-top': '-370px' });
        $('[name=actiontyp]').val("");
        document.getElementById("select_actiontyp").required = true;
        document.getElementById("select_imageurl").required = false;
        document.getElementById("select_buttonurl").required = false;
        document.getElementById("select_buttontext").required = false;
        document.getElementById("select_contenttext").required = false;
        document.getElementById("select_backgroundspread").required = false;
        document.getElementById("select_buttonpicker").required = false;
        document.getElementById("upload_image").required = false;
      }
    });
```

The Modal is only loading according to one condition, it is not able to change on the basis of change in drop-down menu.

I think I am missing something very silly, but not able to figure out.